# How can I simplify an if that's using this confusing function (ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains))

Tags: c#

My code is doing this check:

```
string target = ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(e.Target.Location.OriginalString.Contains);
if (target != "Deck") {

}
```

I understand what it's doing but is there a way I can simplify this to make it a bit more obvious what the intended function is? For example combining these two lines into one.

Comment: Ironically it's hard to understand what it's trying to do. Can you post a working .net fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: I think it's trying to check if e.Target.Location.OriginalString does not contain the word "Deck".  But seems like a very complicated way to be doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach to understanding these problems is to break it down into its simpler form:

```
bool matches = false;
string originalString = e.Target.Location.OriginalString;
foreach (string tab in ListOfTabs)
{
  if (originalString.Contains(tab))
  {
    matches = tab != "Deck";
  }
}

if (matches) 
{
  // do something
}
```

I think this is the long version of your code.

Sometimes writing more code is the better option, for readability.

I think the more readable short hand version would be:

```
string originalString = e.Target.Location.OriginalString;
if (ListOfTabs.FirstOrDefault(x => originalString.Contains(x)) != "Deck")
{
}
```

I'm pretty sure the logic here is still a little odd, and I don't think there is an absolute answer to your question - it's a matter of personal preference.